Extend the space (margin) at the axes of an R plot so that labels, legends and title are not cut off

I'm working on creating a barplot of species richness by taxon group, but the barplot I create cuts off some of the text for my x-axis label and column names. Also, the x-axis title label is shown underneath the text for the x-axis column names. How can I fix these two problems?
barplot(biodiv, xlab = "Taxon Groups", ylab = "Species Richness", 
  ylim = c(0,600), las = 2)


See, e. g. this question. You might also want to use a horizontal barplot (barplot(..., horiz   = TRUE)) to inrease readability, and sort taxa by richness to show the distribution in one go (biodiv$Taxon <- with(biodiv, factor(Taxon, levels = Taxon[order(Richness)])), if the corresponding dataframe columns are named Taxon and Richness).

There are many similar questions on plot margins, labels and legends on Stack Overflow, but it's difficult to find good duplicates as there are so many potential variations. In most cases the answer involves finding the appropriate par() arguments and adjust those to taste. In this case I'm using mar, mgp and cex.axis to solve the issue, but there are alternatives.
First a reproducible example:
areas <- sort(state.x77[,"Area"])[1:5]
barplot(areas, las=2, main="State areas", 
  xlab="State name", ylab="land area in square miles")


Similarly as in your image, the axis legends extends below the lower margin, and the x-axis label is occluded.
mar, a four-length numeric vector, sets the margins, starting at the bottom and continuing round clockwise. Increasing the first two values to 6 increases the bottom and the left margins. mgp, a three-length numeric vector sets the distance between the axis and the labels, legends and lines, respectively. Increasing the first value to 5 moves the axis labels away from the axes. Lastly cex.axis sets the text size of the axis labels, hence reducing it to 0.8 reduces the legend sizes slightly. You can of course set these values to your own tastes, but if you need more flexibility it would probably be better to generate the axes separately using axis().
par(mar=c(6, 6, 2, 1), mgp=c(5, 1, 0), cex.axis=0.8)
barplot(areas, las=2, main="State areas", 
  xlab="State name", ylab="land area in square miles")

# Default values
par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1, mgp=c(3, 1, 0), cex.axis=1)


